# random sampling from a 3-way data cube

Tags: matlab, random

imagine a 2 x 2 x 2 three-way data cube:

```
data = [1 2; 3 4];
data(:,:,2) = [5 6; 7 8]
```

I wish to generate a row-column slice from this cube (i.e. a 2x2 matrix) in which each element of the slice is obtained by randomly sampling its 3-mode fiber (i.e. an nth mode fiber is a vector running along the nth mode/dimension/way. There are 4 3-mode fibers in this cube, one of them is f1 = [1 5], another one is f2 = [2 6] and so on). For example, one slice could turn out to be:

```
slice = [5 2; 3 4]
```

a different sampling might lead to the slice:

```
slice = [1 2; 7 8]
```

Is there a quick way to do this?

I tried using slice = datasample(data,1,3) but this function randomly picks a row-column slice from the cube (i.e. either, slice = [1 2; 3 4] or [5 6; 7 8]).

Comment: Not clear, what is a 3-mode fiber and how is thesampling of the first slice consistent with the second? Elaborate, please.

Comment: The sampling of the first slice is consistent with the sampling of the second slice because in each slice the elements have been randomly generated (uniform sampling) by sampling the "fiber" that that element sits in. For example, to generate element (1,1) you would sample one number from the vector [1 5]. THanks

Comment: I don't get how the first could be a slice. For me, [5,2;7,4] is a diagonal slice.

Comment: I want to generate a 2x2 matrix because 2x2 is one row/col slice through the cube. There are 4 elements in a 2x2 matrix. Let's take the first element, (1,1). Its value should come from uniform random sampling of the vector [1 5]. Lets go to the next element, (1,2). Its value should come from the vector [2 6]. The next element is (2,1) and its value should come from the vector [3 7]. The last element, (2,2), needs a value randomly sampled from the vector [4 8]. I can do all this with loops but I wanted to see if there are faster/simpler ways. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want a generalized solution for the `N`th mode, but I think my answer provides this, using [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to do uniform sampling along dimension `N`;

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for any `nmode` (e.g. `nmode=3` is the 3-mode):

```
data = cat(3,[1 2; 3 4],[5 6; 7 8]);
nmode = 3;
Dn = size(data,nmode);
modeSampleInds = randi(Dn,1,numel(data)/Dn); % here is the random sample
dp = reshape(permute(data,[nmode setdiff(1:ndims(data),nmode)]), Dn, []);
outSize = size(data); outSize(nmode)=1;
slice = reshape(dp(sub2ind(size(dp),modeSampleInds,1:size(dp,2))),outSize)
```

Note that this does not require the Statistics Toolbox.  It is also completely generalized for any matrix size, number of dimension, and "N-mode fiber".

I'd be glad to explain each line if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then it's quite simple actually. You have four 3-mode fibers and you wish to construct a 2x2 matrix where each element was sampled from the corresponding fiber.
So, you need to sample 4 times (one for each fiber) one element out of 2 (each fiber has two elements):

```
>> [h w fiberSize] = size(data); % make the solution more general
>> fIdx = randsample( fiberSize, h*w ); % sample with replacements
```

After sampling we construct the slice, for simplicity I'll "flatten" the 3D data into a 2D matrix

```
>> fData = reshape( data, [], fiberSize );
>> slice = fData( sub2ind( [h*w fiberSize], 1:(h*w), fIdx ) );
>> slice = reshape( slice, [h w] ); % shape the slice
```

Comment: a little more complicated since the sampling is not from 1:fiberSize. The sampling is from a vector of arbitrary values taken from the cube(the 3rd-mode fiber specific to the element in question). In the example i used 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 to fill the cube but this was only to put values in there. Imagine any random values in there. I could have specified that more clearly. Thank you.

Comment: @val this is exactly why I use `sub2ind` to convert the sampled values 1:fiberSize` to values drawn from `data`. Please give my code a try and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is valid for any cube size. No toolbox required.

```
N = size(data,1); %//length of side of cube
r = randi(N,1,N^2)-1; %//this is the random sampling
data_permuted = permute(data,[3 1 2]); %//permute so that sampling is along first dim
slice = data_permuted((1:N:N^3)+r); %//sample using linear indexing 
slice = reshape(slice.',N,N); %//reshape into a matrix
```

Comment: sampling here is 1:N. sampling should be arbitrary from the n-mode fiber specific to the element. (see comments below). I think here we are sticking specifically to the structure of my simple example. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "sampling here is 1:N"? Sampling is actually random among all elements within each 3-mode fiber. And that's what you want, isn't it? In your example 2x2x2 case, the value of the (1,1) element comes from uniform random sampling of the vector [1 5] (I'm using your values just as an example); the (1,2) element comes from the vector [2 6], and so on. Have you actually _tried_ my code?